# Extremely high gas Limit for ethereum function execution

Tags: solidity

I am trying to call a function from my smart contract.
The function i am trying to call is `convertRTKIntoRTKLX`

(Full code :- [swapContract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x3c925011c1869eb785f9eb9050f42141644aa21b#code))

Although, the necessary code for this question is only this much:-

```
function convertRTKIntoRTKLX(address to, uint256 amount, uint256 X) public returns (bool) {
    require (
        (X >= 2 && X <= 5), 
        "Invalid value of X. X can only be 2, 3, 4, 5"
    );
    
    require (
        amount > 0,
        "Cannot convert 0"
    );
    
    ERC20 AMMOToken = ERC20(_Token_AMMO);
    ERC20 RTKToken = ERC20(_Token_RTKL[0]);
    ERC20 RTKLXToken = ERC20(_Token_RTKL[X-1]);
    
    require (
        RTKLXToken.balanceOf(address(this)) >= amount,
        "Insufficeint RTKLX Token balance in the contract for the given value of X"
    );
    
    require (
        RTKToken.allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) >= amount,
        "Allowance Lower than required for RTKToken"
    );
    
    require (
        AMMOToken.allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) >= ((X-1)*amount),
        "Allowance Lower than required for bulletToken"
    );
    

    if(AMMOToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), ((X-1)*amount))) {
        if(RTKToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount)) {
            if(RTKLXToken.transfer(to, amount)) {
                _RTKLX_ExtCirculation[X-1] += amount;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            AMMOToken.transfer(msg.sender, (X-1)*amount);
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now i call this function with X = 2, and some valid address. Consider these 2 cases --

a) amount =  10 x (10^18)         <---  mentioned in this format for easier understanding
b) amount = 150 x (10^18)

Now, for case a, the gas limit is fine and comes less than 200,000
But for case b, the gas limit comes around 11,874,898

(NOTE :- Before executing this function, i have approved 1000 x (10^18) RTK and AMMO token.)

Can anyone tell me why is gas limit going so high ?

When i test it on remix, the gas limit only comes around 175,000

Comment: The gas limit is so high likely because one of the statements in your code reverts. The fact that you get a reasonable gas limit when passing an amount 10 tokens but not when passing an amount 150 tokens, implies that it is likely because you don't have a balance of (at least) 150 tokens in your account.

Comment: Yes, That was the issue. Thanks for help. I realised that too late. This was a really stupid question to ask.

Answer (score 1):

As answered by @goodvibration in the comments, the reason for this issue is the fact that the contract's balance was not sufficient and the transaction was getting reverted.